# Android Parse.com return corrupted json

Tags: java, android, json, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com services for an Android application but when I try to get datas from Parse, an error occurs:

```
com.parse.ParseException: corrupted json: org.json.JSONException: No value for code
```

Here is the code I use to get the datas:

```
public void getCategories() {
    listCategories = new ArrayList<>();

    ParseQuery<Category> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Category.class);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Category>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<Category> categories, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // Clear previously loaded Categories
                listCategories.clear();
                for (Category category : categories) {
                    // Fill the list with retrieved Categories
                    lsistCategories.add(category);
                }
            }else {
               Log.d("Error happened while retrieving data:", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Any idea of what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace and what JSON you receive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, in fact I forgot to register my custom Category class in my Application class.

I added this to the onCreate method in my Application class and now it works:

```
ParseObject.registerSubclass(Category.class);
```